# PHP and SQL Server 2000 - odbc_connect not working and NO ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: php, sql-server-2000

I tried re-run the earlier working code to connect SQL Server 2000 from PHP.   I used the following code to connect:

```
$connection = odbc_connect($databaseURL, $databaseUName, $databasePWord);

if (!$connection) {
    echo 'dyeing';
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to database ' + $databaseName);
}
else
{
    echo "connection successful";
}
```

But no code, after $connection = odbc_connect($databaseURL, $databaseUName, $databasePWord);

is working.   Not even echo statements.

What will be wrong in the setup.  I formated and re-installed windows, php and sql server et all.   Earlier the same code working fine.

Now no message appears after the line odbc_connect statement.    Till that line, every echo statement is working fine.

Couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Happiness Always
BKR Shivaprakkash

Comment: Chances are the odbc extension is not installed *(that would cause a fatal error when trying to call the undefined function odbc_connect)* ; check the ouput of phpinfo() ; and if odbc is not installed, install it.

Comment: phpinfo() list ODBC support as enabled;   Is there any other way to check it.  I'm new to PHP.
odbc
ODBC Support enabled
Active Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0
ODBC library  Win32

Comment: Oh, too bad :-( maybe someone else will have a better idea, then... in the meantime, you might want to check if error_reporting and display_errors are enabled, to try getting an error message displaed *(it might help find what the problem is)*

Comment: Well,  display_errors was set to Off and I turned it On.   Now it's displaying the error message
Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I removed the ODBC definition in User DSN and created in System DSN and now it's connecting.  Thanks Pascal.

Comment: You mostly helped yourself, but glad you found out what the problem was :-) *(as you have found out the answer, you might want to post that as an answer to your question, and accept it, to indicate that you don't need anyone to try answering)*

Comment: What else I should add / do, to use mssql_connect  to connect sql server 2000 from PHP ?  Any help ?

Comment: if you want to use mssql_* function, you'll have to enable the corresponding extension ; and, then, modify your code to those functions.

Comment: @Sivaa just to remember to reset the Server. And mssql_ is somewhat deprecated.